# SystemExit not catched by unittest when in except block

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing

I have test which checks if method will raise `SystemExit`.
When metod uses `sys.exit()` directly, test will catch it properly. Problem is with following code:

```
def module(x):
    try:
        int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print('Wrong value')
        sys.exit()
```

Program is terminated, but test fails with `AssertionError: SystemExit not raised`.
I don't understand what is wrong. Even if I will change last line to `raise SystemExit` the test will fail.

//edit

Here is my test declaration:

```
def test_id_not_number(self):
    with self.assertRaises(SystemExit, self) as cm:
        module('id')
        self.assertEqual(cm.exception, "Error")
```

Comment: Well, what is `x` in that case? If `int(x)` succeeds, then the test correctly fails.

Comment: `Wrong value` is printed, so int(x) fails. Updated my sample code.

Comment: Can you please show us full test? I can't see assertion for `SystemExit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `assertRaises` is used as context manager, it should take only one input argument - a type of exception to catch.

Additional arguments should be used only in form:

```
self.assertRaises(exc_type, callable, *args, **kwargs)
```

Following code:

```
import sys
import unittest


def f(x):
    try:
        int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print('Wrong value')
        sys.exit()


class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_id_not_number(self):
        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
            f('id')
            self.assertEqual(cm.exception, "Error")

unittest.main()
```

Produces output:

```
Wrong value
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed that. Other tests was without self, but wasn't in except block so I thought it was the problem. Thank you.